# Moving 'save' dialog for pdfs moves the entire (background) firefox screen

Tags: gnome, firefox

This is what I mean: 
[image] 
I'm trying to move the dialog so I can read the title of what I'm trying to save, but that's not working.

Comment: Antifeature from hell!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that modal dialogs are attached to the main window. You can disable it using `gnome-tweak-tool`, or using `gsettings`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter attach-modal-dialogs false
```

With `gnome-tweak-tool`, install it first:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then use it to disable "attached modal dialogs" (exact location of the setting may vary, but that should be the name):

[image]

Comment: Who the hell made this strange behavior default?! Who the hell made it existing at all?!