# Saving a document with evince blocks scrolling in the background

Tags: gui, evince, scrolling

When I open a PDF downloaded from the web in evince and I want to create a local copy of said PDF, I open the "Save as" dialog box. This is all quite normal.

However, the dialog is placed in a fixed manner relative to the window showing the document, covering most of it. Since, the dialog box can not be moved, the dialog-window blocks the document behind it.

If I want to create a file name for the PDF of a scientific paper from its "meta-data", e.g., authors, year of publication, title, etc., as in my use case; then the ability to scroll the document in the background or to move the dialog-window out of the way would be quite handy.

[image]

I have the gut-feeling that this worked in previous versions of Ubuntu/GNOME and evince.

Did some design paradigm of the UI of evince or of Ubuntu/GNOME in general change over time?

---

The issue with moving the dialog-window out of the way, has been also addressed by this question, and a solution is available there: attached modal dialogs.
However, scrolling is still not possible.

[Moving 'save' dialog for pdfs moves the entire (background) firefox screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/555847/moving-save-dialog-for-pdfs-moves-the-entire-background-firefox-screen)

---

[Relevant XKCD is relevant](https://xkcd.com/1172/)